# Dynamically create CheckBox and call a function with Onchange Event

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically creating a checkbox. Now I want to call a function(lets say Hello world) whenever the checkbox is checked. I used setAttribute to call the function, but I am facing problems while passing parameters. I want the values of i and j to be passed to function.
Following is my code -

```
function addTable(message) {
 var paxArray=new Array();
 var mealsArray= new Array();
 mealsArray=['Vegeterian Food','Non Vegeterian Food', 'Indian  Continental','Chinese'];
paxArray=message.data;
for(var i=0;i<paxArray.length;i++){
  var x= document.createElement('tr');
  x.innerHTML=paxArray[i];
  document.getElementById("Content").appendChild(x);
     for(var j=0;j<mealsArray.length;j++){
         var row=document.createElement('tr');
         var meal=document.createElement('td');
         var check_box=document.createElement('td');
         var check=document.createElement('input');
         check.type="checkbox";
         check.id="checkbox"+i+j;
         check.setAttribute("onchange","Helloworld(i+j);");
         meal.innerHTML=mealsArray[j];
         check_box.appendChild(check)
         row.appendChild(check_box);
         row.appendChild(meal);
         document.getElementById("Content").appendChild(row); 
   }
 }
}


   function Helloworld(index){
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=index;
  }
```

Comment: There's a perfectly fine onchange javascript property that you can set. Why attribute? and "i+j" does not exist in the html context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i+j you are passing are simply characters not variable values. 
Try:
  say `var i = 4; var j=3;`
if you want to call `Helloworld(43)`

```
check.setAttribute("onchange","Helloworld("+i+j+");");
```

if you want to call `Helloworld(7)`

```
var k=i+j;
check.setAttribute("onchange","Helloworld("+k+");");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
function assignFunction(i, j) {
    return function() {
        Helloworld(i+j);
    }
}
check.onchange = assignFunction(i+j);
```

Comment: Yes, It did worked. But whenever click any checkbox, '6' is the number which always gets updated. 6, which is addition of length of both arrays.

Comment: oh yeah, it's because it's evaluated when it's being run (changed).

Comment: Updated to valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
check.setAttribute("onchange",`"Helloworld(" + (i + j) + ");"`);
```

If you don't use (i + j) and put just "Helloworld(" + i + j + ");", you will get concatenation and not sum